# Azure Virtual Machine Configure Custom Domain

Tags: azure, dns, virtual, configure

I have created a website using linux Virtual machine in Azure. Default name of the machine is abc.cloudapp.net. I have entered machine IP address in A record using Godaddy and redirection is fine. But when i typed abc.com in browser, this redirect to abc.cloudapp.net which is fine too but also shows this abc.cloudapp.net in the address bar which is not correct. Any help

Comment: Have you tried setting the CNAME record as well?

Comment: I already forwarded CName record (www to abc.Cloudapp.net) but it is not working as well

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: it does work with me , dont know your problem, maybe propagation time?